# Get Most Recent Insert In LiteDB c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq, litedb

I'm working on creating a method that gets the last transaction inserted into litedb.

I do have a datestring, that is saved.

Here is the class:

```
public class TransactionPair : TransactionTwo
{
    private string returnT;
    public TransactionPair() { /* making an empty declaration so we don't NEED to pass it anything if we don't want. */}

    public TransactionPair(string returnT, string request)
    {
        this.returnT = returnT;
        JObject o = JObject.Parse(returnT);
        AuthCode = o.GetValue("AuthoCode").ToString();
        TransType = o.GetValue("TransType").ToString();
        AmountString = o.GetValue("AmountString").ToString();
        CardType = o.GetValue("CardType").ToString();
        Last4 = o.GetValue("Last4").ToString();
        RefID = o.GetValue("RefID").ToString();
        CardToken = o.GetValue("CardToken").ToString();
        ExpDate = o.GetValue("ExpDate").ToString();
        DateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss.f", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
        Request = request;
    }

    public string Request { get; set; }
}
```

here is the insertion method for the transaciton pair.

```
  public void InsertTransactionPair(string json, string request)
    {
        JObject transObj = JObject.Parse(json);

        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(connectionString))
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<TransactionPair>("TransactionPair");
            var transactionTwo = new TransactionPair
            {
                AuthCode = GetValue(transObj, "AuthCode"),
                TransType = GetValue(transObj, "TransType"),
                AmountString = GetValue(transObj, "AmountString"),
                CardType = GetValue(transObj, "CardType"),
                Last4 = GetValue(transObj, "Last4"),
                RefID = GetValue(transObj, "RefID"),
                CardToken = GetValue(transObj, "CardToken"),
                DateString = DateTime.Now.ToString("d-MMM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss.f", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo),
                Request = request
            };
            collection.Insert(transactionTwo);

            collection.EnsureIndex(x => x.RefID);
        }
    }
```

I need either a Linq method of finding the most recent entry, or is it like a queue where I can just pop off the first value in the return query and get the most recent one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, records in LiteDB are ordered by the primary key (`_id` by default) when you query them. From the code you provided I couldn't tell what data type the primary key is, but if it is an integer and is not manually set, then you could simply look up the last record:

```
collection.FindOne(Query.All(Query.Descending))
```

If your primary keys are not guaranteed to be in order (for example, if the data type is `Guid`), then you'll need to use another approach. Unfortunately, I don't think the DateString will be much help: any queries that sort on it would sort alphabetically, rather than chronologically. If possible, I recommend using a `DateTime` property to store the current timestamp, rather than storing it as a `string`. Doing so would allow you to sort the records easily, for example:

```
collection.EnsureIndex("Timestamp");
collection.FindOne(Query.All("Timestamp", Query.Descending));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Guid contains some RawValue infos like CreationTime(system.datetime), Increment, Machine, Pid, Timestamp. Maybe you can use them in your query.

Comment: That is interesting. I will try that as well. Thank you.